# How to change the font of a specific tab in QTabWidget in Pyside2?

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyside2, qtabwidget

After an event is triggered, I want to change the font of a specific tab to use a bold font, rather than non-bold.

```
qtabwidget.tabs[4].setFontWeight(Bold)
```

How to do this?

Comment: There are no individual "tabs", QTabBar draws all the "tabs"

Comment: You clearly have an XY problem since you ask how to implement a possible solution(that nobody guarantees that it works): *How to get the current tab of QTabWidget* instead of asking about the underlying problem: *how to set the font to bold from the current tab*

Comment: Thanks, so what's the way to change the stylesheet for a specific tab? Should I update the questions?

Comment: 1) You must rewrite your question, 2) To change the font, not only Qt StyleSheet can be used, so instead of asking about it, not only questions: how to change the font of the current tab?

Comment: what do you get when you run: `print(QApplication.style(),metaObject().className())`?

Comment: Is that a . before metaObject()? If so I get QStyleSheetStyle.

Comment: If you use  `QApplication.setStyle("fusion")` change something you don't want?

Comment: It says wrong argument type, expects QStyle.

Comment: mmm, use `QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))`

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: okay, I just wanted to check that my possible solution does not generate problems

Comment: oh i see what you mean now

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use a QProxyStyle:

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class TabBarStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawControl(self, element, option, painter, widget=None):
        index = -1
        if element == QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTab:
            if isinstance(widget, TabBar):
                for i in widget.fonts.keys():
                    if widget.tabRect(i) == option.rect:
                        index = i
                        break
            if index > -1:
                painter.save()
                painter.setFont(widget.fonts[index])
        super(TabBarStyle, self).drawControl(element, option, painter, widget)
        if index > -1:
            painter.restore()


class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TabBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self._fonts = dict()

    @property
    def fonts(self):
        return self._fonts


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.tab_bar = TabBar()
        self.tabbar_style = TabBarStyle(self.tab_bar.style())
        self.tab_bar.setStyle(self.tabbar_style)
        self.tab_widget.setTabBar(self.tab_bar)

        self.tab_widget.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), "Foo")
        self.tab_widget.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), "Bar")
        self.tab_widget.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), "Baz")

        font = self.tab_widget.font()
        font.setBold(True)
        self.tab_bar.fonts[1] = font
        self.tab_bar.update()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, where do you specify which tab to set bold in code? Does this code set a specific tab bold?

Comment: In your initial question you wanted to change the font of the selected element ... I have noticed that you have changed your focus on it too, let me correct that.

Comment: Yes no worries :)

Comment: Somehow after running the code I am getting this error: Internal C++ object (Pyside2.QtWidgets.QStyle) already deleted, and crash. I copied everything but only it doesn't crash if I stop at self.tab_bar = TabBar(). If I add the next line, the same error happens. So it's stemming from there for some reason.

Comment: Also why something trivial in other GUI frameworks that can be done with a single line of code, often requires a lot of code to do the same thing? As an expert in Qt, do you think it's a design flaw or just shortsightedness?